# How to listen CustomEvent on Firefox (Extension) from external website?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension

I aim to listen to some messages to my extension from my website.

For this example let's assume that I own yahoo.com and I created an extension that will run on top of google.com

In my Firefox extension I added this in content_script which is

```
window.addEventListener("PassToBackground", function(evt) {
  console.log(evt)
}, false);
```

Now from my google.com if I send this message it will not appear on the google.com console.

```
var message = {"status": true};
var event = new CustomEvent("PassToBackground", {detail: message});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

How do I receive messages from external websites to the firefox extension?

Note: How can the Grammarly communicate with extension from moz-extension:id or something.?

Comment: Your code is already doing it correctly. If there's no console output it may be a timing problem e.g. the content script runs after DOMContentLoaded by default but the site sends the message prior to that. You can specify run_at in your content_scripts declaration.

Comment: I've to click my extension icon to inject the script which I did after the DOMContentLoaded I think but I believe the problem lies somewhere for example if I send the message on the google.com console tab it sent the message but not on yahoo.com console tab.

Comment: Since the posted code is correct you'll have to make a fuller [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to listen to the custom event that the external website that you don't own in the content-script?

Comment: Hi Envil. One correction from your query which is `custom event from the external website`